# Android: How can you stop Screenshots or copying text

Tags: android

I want to stop a user from copying text or images from my screen to any text editor.

Also I want to prevent taking screen shots of activities.

How can I do it programmatically in Android?

Comment: Use getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
before setContentView();

Answer (score 4):

In terms of screenshots - try using `FLAG_SECURE` - as the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE) state

> Window flag: treat the content of the window as secure, preventing it from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays.

You can use it in an Activity as follows:

```
public class NonScreenshotableActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Place this before setting layout but after calling super method
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                         LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    //Rest of your activity code here
  }
}
```

You can also stop any `EditText` fields from being copy/pasteable by using the following:

```
yourEditText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

You can see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html) for `ActionMode.Callback()` for more on this but it essentially aborts loading the copy/paste dialog

Answer (score 0):

Ed George answers the first part!

**Here is the Second half**

If you are using API level 11 or above then you can stop copy,paste,cut and custom context menus from appearing by.

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Returning false from onCreateActionMode(ActionMode, Menu) will prevent the action mode from being started(Select All, Cut, Copy and Paste actions).